# How do I account for different case selections in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, mysql-workbench

What I want to do is simple. **I would like a user to provide a valid input ("IR1" or "IR2" or "IR3"), have a message pop up saying "IR1 Selected" or "IR2 Selected" or "IR3 Selected", then have the user click the Submit Button & the report should populate with the table & relevant data from the MySQL database.**

Here is the VBA code I have now

> 

```
Sub querydatafromMySQL_Report_2()

Dim cntMyConnection As ADODB.Connection
Set cntMyConnection = New ADODB.Connection
cntMyConnection.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI 
Driver};Server=localhost;Database=ie465hw3;Uid=root; pwd=12345678; OPTION=3;"

cntMyConnection.Open
Dim rstFirstRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set rstFirstRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim src As String

src = InputBox("Please Enter RoomID", "Room ID")
If src = Empty Then Exit Sub

Select Case src
Case "IR1"
src = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE StartTime>'17:00:00' AND RoomID = 'IR1'"
MsgBox "Room IR1 Selected "


Case "IR2"
src = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE StartTime>'17:00:00' AND RoomID = 'IR2'"
MsgBox "Room IR2 Selected "


Case "IR3"
RoomID = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE StartTime>'17:00:00' AND RoomID = 'IR3'"
MsgBox "Room IR3 Selected "

Case Else
MsgBox "Invalid RoomID, choose either RoomID: IR1, IR2, or IR3"


End Select

rstFirstRecordset.Open Source:=src, ActiveConnection:=cntMyConnection
 Worksheets("Report_2").Activate
 Dim column As Integer, row As Integer
 With ActiveSheet

 row = 11
 While Not rstFirstRecordset.EOF
 For column = 1 To rstFirstRecordset.Fields.Count
 .Cells(row, column) = rstFirstRecordset(column - 1).Value
 Next column
 rstFirstRecordset.MoveNext
 row = row + 1
 Wend
 End With
 Set rstFirstRecordset = Nothing
 cntMyConnection.Close
 Set cntMyConnection = Nothing
 MsgBox "MySQL DB Connected & Data Report Printed"
 End Sub
```

IR1 & IR2 works fine but when I provide "IR3" I get this error

[image: Error]

Then when I try to debug this is the 1st line of code it goes to, what is the problem?

> 

```
 rstFirstRecordset.Open Source:=src, ActiveConnection:=cntMyConnection
```

This is how it should look like before a user does anything
[image: User-Interface-Pre-Report]

This is how it should look like after a user has provided valid input & clicked the Submit Button.
[image: User-Interface-Post-Report]

Comment: You have too many "select case". Select case should only be written once, then case.... Case... See example at the bottom in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement not sure if that is the issue but it's not correct at least. So start with fixing that. I believe what you have done is that you nested your cases. So case 1 has to be true for case2 to be evaluated and so on. And that can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
Select Case src
    Case "IR1"
        ' Code here
    Case "IR1"
        ' Code here
    Case "IR1"
        ' Code here
    Case Else
        ' Code here
End Select
```

Comment: Got it now! Thank you.